# Preventing an ng-repeat redrawing entire row

Tags: angularjs

If you check the following jsfiddle you will see an example of a problem I am having.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yram7/1/

My problem is that when an ng-repeat has a very simple data type driving it such as an array of numbers, eg `[1..10]` when the array is updated, angularjs somehow knows the data valuse have not changed, and hence does not redraw the row DOM. This means that pieces of UI such as a dropdown box can be used in combination with a setInterval causing the data to refresh.

All is good.

However if I change the data structure behind the ng-repeat to contain complex objects, eg `[{"i" : 1}..{"i" : 10}]`angularjs redraws the row entirely (even though the values HAVEN'T changed although of course the object references have) and hence if a drop down was selected, the html is destroyed by repainting the row, and hence a poor UI experience as the user selection is not preserved.

Try fiddling with the select options and clicking the drop down arrow to see what I mean.

Is it possible to somehow prevent this behaviour so that the DOM only redraws if it finds some kind of change in the row data values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your fiddle, you are using ant antique version of Angular. More recent versions have the `track by` clause in `ng-repeat` ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat)).

Here is your fiddle forked that implements it with the `track by` and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/BFFJn/

The `track by` clause will associate the iterated object's identity with the DOM, so that when a (possibly different) object with the same id is found, the DOM is updated, not replaced. If no `track by` is given, object equality is used.

Comment: Aha, I had used track by for nested ng-repeats before, didn't realise it could be used for this as well, that is very helpful, many thanks.